# making datagrid addrow feature to work with entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

i am writing this simple app that has two main tables one for picture information and another for a list of parameters about pictures just like picture below
[image]

I want to be able to add into parameters list inline without any other forms but when i add a row it adds another row correctly into database but saving the text entered doesn't works.(I am saving changes in "RowEditEnding" event)
here is XAML:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Margin="10">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ListBox Name="lstPicture" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding pictures, Mode=OneWayToSource}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="ID">
            </ListBox>
            <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="جدید" Height="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
        </Grid>
        <GroupBox Header="اطلاعات تصویر" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,10,10">
            <!--Image Data Grid-->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200px"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <!--Image Data Right Grid-->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="100px"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <materialDesign:Card Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image Name="imgPreview" Margin="5" Source="{Binding SelectedItem.URL, ElementName=lstPicture}" MouseLeftButtonUp="Image_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                        </Image>
                    </materialDesign:Card>
                    <!--Image Data Fields-->
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100px"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                            </Style>
                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignTextBox}" TargetType="TextBox">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                            </Style>
                            <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedButton}" TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <TextBlock Text="نام تصویر"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=lstPicture}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="عکاس" Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Author, ElementName=lstPicture}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="انتخاب تصویر" Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Button Name="btnChooseImage" Content="..." Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Height="Auto" Click="btnChooseImage_Click"/>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
                <DataGrid Name="dgrdQuestions" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.tests, ElementName=lstPicture,Converter={StaticResource ObservableCollectionConverter},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="True" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" RowEditEnding="dgrdQuestions_RowEditEnding" AddingNewItem="DataGrid_AddingNewItem">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}" Header="عنوان" Width="1*"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Name="btnAddQuestion" Header="جدید" Click="btnAddQuestion_Click"/>
                            <MenuItem Name="btnDeleteQuestion" Header="حذف" Click="btnDeleteQuestion_Click"/>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
```

and here is code:

```
public AdminPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    lstPicture.ItemsSource = App.Entities.pictures.ToList();
}

private void DataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    App.Entities.SaveChanges();
}

private void DataGrid_AddingNewItem(object sender, AddingNewItemEventArgs e)
{
    App.Entities.tests.Add(new test { pictureID = (int)lstPicture.SelectedValue });
    App.Entities.SaveChanges();
}
```

p.s:I always have such problems with WPF binding and entity framework that makes me use hacky ways to solve it. i would appreciate if someone explains to me the normal way to go with binding that doesn't cause such problems

Answer (score 0):

Since EF doesn't know about your changed entity (it was changed by the ModelBinder and not EF itself, we need to tell EF that the object exists and that it is a modified App.Entities.Entry(test).State = EnitityState.Modified;

```
var datag = (DataGrid) sender;
var t = (Test) datag.SelectedValue;
App.Entities.Entry(test).State = EnitityState.Modified;
App.Entities.SaveChanges();
```

If the object not in this given DbContext for any reason, then you have to find it by Id and then change it and after that you can call App.Entities.SaveChanges();

Comment: i have added said code in CellEditEnding part but it throws this exception:An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: @MojtabaIranpanah this is an known error in EF but unfortunately, the error message does not clear what does the error exactly means! This error happened when the entity Id = 0 or the entity is not in the same db context you have to search for the entity in the dbContext before you change it!